# mvc -> changing case of controllername breaks rendering

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

In chrome, if i go to www.mysite.com/controller/foo the page renders perfectly

In chrome, if i go to www.mysite.com/Controller/foo the page renders but the sizing and other css attributes break.

In I.E. if i go to www.mysite.com/controller/foo the page renders but my divs are 2 pixels high.

In I.E. if i go towww.mysite.com/Controller/foo the page breaks exactly like it does in chrome.

Firefox works exactly like I.E.

I've checked for duplicate Id's, looked for problems with my jquery, googled (ive read apache is case sensitive. That might matter to me if i werent on iis) etc and i am completely stumped. Has anyone ever seen this before?

Thanks

Comment: are you looking in the dev tools? Hit F12, reload the page and see if any errors are cast. There's likely something that's case sensitive that isn't working. The pixel differences might be a browser issue.

Comment: yes sir, tried that and don't see anything that sticks out.

Comment: maybe one version is cached.. clear your cache and reload the pages

Comment: i thought that as well but no dice.

Comment: it was a css issue. i changed classes and it stopped. When im not knee deep in a release ill go back and find out why and update with an answer

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your static files fail to load at the different paths likely means you're not using proper relative paths, i.e. they're relative to the current path not to the entire domain (`css/foo.css` vs. `/Controller/foo/css/foo.css`). You shouldn't really be making your static files relative to any particular controller anyways, for what it's worth, but if you are going to do something like that, you definitely need to spell out the full path off the domain and not just a partial stub.

It's also important to remember that while the Windows filesystem is not case-sensitive, search engines are, so `Controller/foo` and `controller/foo` are two entirely different pages. If you want consistent URLs you should enable `routes.LowercaseUrls = true` in your route config.

Comment: At first i wanted to say no because the scripts are loaded in the layout (and i checked view source to verify they are indeed domain-centric) but i did create one jquery file that i added that may not be. let me check that one. if thats it ill upvote

Comment: no sir. all my content urls are relative to the domain i.e. "/viewscripts/foo.js"